# What is the default call of keyboard shortcuts in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I am trying to find what is being called when I press a keyboard shortcut. For example, if I hit Ctrl + Alt + L I block the screen, or when I hit the "mute" key in my keyboard I mute the sound. I can't find where those bindings are stored.

I have found the list of bindings in `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings`, but I don't see there the effect of the key, just that it is a shortcut.
I am not looking for the window where the shortcuts are listed ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6KyF.png)) but I want what the shortcuts are calling.

For example, if I create a new shortcut, which executes a shell script, it's easy to see what it is calling, just clicking on the name (in the said window [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6KyF.png)), but if it's a default shortcut, clicking on the name disables the shortcut, so I want to know what the shortcut executes when it's activated.

I'm using Gnome Shell (not Unity) in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/r3bmyw/export_keyboard_shortcuts/?rdt=62863) Reddit thread, keyboard shortcuts are stored in dconf, which is binary file, not a text file. I think that's why you cannot directly find what is called when you press a keyboard shortcut. However, you can find this information if you first dump all the keybinding settings in dconf to a text file, and then go and peruse it :). This also explained in the cited Reddit thread. The command to do that is:

```bash
$ dconf dump / > mysettings.conf
```

I used this approach to find out the "text definition" of some shortcuts I defined to switch among workspaces, in the GUI keyboard shortcuts settings (I'm using Ubuntu 22.04).

You could define shortcuts from the command line as well, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423846/how-can-i-add-shortcuts-to-move-windows-to-workspace-5-and-above), for example.

Last, command `xmodmap -pke` I got from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224356/what-is-the-default-call-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome) tells you how GNOME calls, or labels, all the shifted characters in the keyboard, such as `#` (Shift+3), or `%` (Shift+5), in an English keyboard layout. This comes in handy if you use the command line to define shortcuts!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows key on your computer hold that down for a couple seconds. hope that helps :P

Comment: It doesn't work. At least not in gnome-shell.

Comment: could you tell me what version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, it is written in the question

Comment: http://linux.about.com/library/gnome/blgnome1n2a.htm

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. That link is also a list of shortcuts, but it doesn't say what is being called.

Comment: being called? ..

Comment: I mean, when I use a shortcut, a piece of software is executed. I want to know what is being executed, if it's a script, or a binary or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Search for Keyboard Shortcuts in unity. Should help.

Comment: I'm not using Unity, I use Gnome-shell

Comment: Isn't there Keyboard Shortcuts in it too? I'm sorry, I dont use it :/ Keyboard Shortcuts is usually found in Settings window.

Comment: [this](http://www.techotopia.com/images/7/7d/Ubuntu_keyboard_shortcuts2.jpg) is how it looks like.

Comment: yes, there's a window exactly like that, but that only tells me what effect the shortcut has, but I want to find what is being called, if it is a script, or something

Comment: Ahh. That was the `/usr/share...` you were talking about? Well. I dont know anymore.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this gives you everything you want to know, but if you run this command:

```
xmodmap -pke | less
```

You will get output on what every key on the keyboard does.  It's a little cryptic because you don't get names just keycodes.

Excerpt from my machine:

```
keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar
keycode  14 = 5 percent 5 percent
keycode  15 = 6 asciicircum 6 asciicircum
keycode  16 = 7 ampersand 7 ampersand
keycode  17 = 8 asterisk 8 asterisk
keycode  18 = 9 parenleft 9 parenleft
keycode  19 = 0 parenright 0 parenright
keycode  20 = minus underscore minus underscore
keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  24 = q Q q Q
keycode  25 = w W w W
keycode  26 = e E e E
keycode  27 = r R r R
keycode  28 = t T t T
keycode  29 = y Y y Y
keycode  30 = u U u U
```