# Is it possible to see what is the command executed for default Keyboard Shortcuts? Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I open keyboard shortcuts from system settings.
I see this

[image]

for example, I want to know "view-split on left" Super+Left is there an executable command for this? where can I find it?

[image]

I have gone through this [Q & A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224356/what-is-the-default-call-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome) but no clue.