# How can I add shortcuts to move windows to workspace 5 and above

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I can add additional workspaces in the Multitasking option in Settings.

Now in Keyboard shortcuts under Navigation, I can have shortcuts to "move window to workspace x" till workspace number 4.

But I just added workspace 5.

Where can I set a set a shortcut to directly move a window to workspace 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings for higher workspace numbers are not anymore exposed in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" dialog, but can be set using dconf-editor or with a `gsettings` command. For example, to assign <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
gsettings set "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" "switch-to-workspace-5" "['<Super>F5']" 
gsettings set "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" "move-to-workspace-5" "['<Super><Shift>F5']"
```

Leave out the last argument, and change `set` to `reset` to reset the setting to default.

Comment: Where can I see the gsettings? Is there a separate config file for that? And do these survive a OS version update?

Comment: Ok, I found from the man page how I can see all the bindings. The second question ^ still remains.